# Get Started button not showing up on Facebook Messenger when going through the m.me link

Tags: facebook-messenger

The Get Started button is not showing up on the Facebook Messenger Bot's welcome screen when going through the m.me link. However, if we search for the Bot/App we can see the Get Started button on the welcome screen.
Has anyone encountered such a situation? Or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I just ran into this issue also. Last time the welcome screen was showing but not now. This is a video about the issue. https://youtu.be/ikqZHPubdYo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went to the Facebook support website and found out that there is a valid report for this issue. I think, we have to wait for them to fix it.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/695387230830209/?disable_redirect=0